# Read data from MySQL to Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read data from MySQL and show on the Datagridview with code as below:

```
Dim totalManagerQuantity As Integer
Dim totalStaffQuantity As Integer
Dim totalProductionQuantity As Integer
Dim totalSalesManager As Double
Dim totalSalesStaff As Double
Dim totalSalesProduction As Double
        sqL = "SELECT TDate, InvoiceNo,
                  (
                    SELECT TD.Quantity
                    FROM TransactionDetails as TD
                    WHERE TD.InvoiceNo = T.InvoiceNo
                    AND TD.ProductNo = 1
                  ) as ManagerQuantity,
                  ( 
                    SELECT TD.ItemPrice
                    FROM TransactionDetails as TD
                    WHERE TD.InvoiceNo = T.InvoiceNo
                    AND TD.ProductNo = 1
                  ) as ManagerPrice,
                  (
                    SELECT TD.Quantity
                    FROM TransactionDetails as TD
                    WHERE TD.InvoiceNo = T.InvoiceNo
                    AND TD.ProductNo = 2
                  ) as StaffQuantity,
                  ( 
                    SELECT TD.ItemPrice
                    FROM TransactionDetails as TD
                    WHERE TD.InvoiceNo = T.InvoiceNo
                    AND TD.ProductNo = 2
                  ) as StaffPrice,
                  ( 
                    SELECT TD.Quantity
                    FROM TransactionDetails as TD
                    WHERE TD.InvoiceNo = T.InvoiceNo
                    AND TD.ProductNo = 3
                  ) as ProductionQuantity,
                  ( 
                    SELECT TD.ItemPrice
                    FROM TransactionDetails as TD
                    WHERE TD.InvoiceNo = T.InvoiceNo
                    AND TD.ProductNo = 3
                  ) as ProductionPrice
           FROM Transactions as T
           WHERE TDate BETWEEN '" & frmFilterReportInvoice.dtpStartDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "'
           AND '" & frmFilterReportInvoice.dtpEndDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "'
           AND StaffID = '" & lblTempStaffID.Text & "'"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        dgvReportInvoice.Rows.Clear()
        dgvTotalQuantity.Rows.Clear()
        totalManagerQuantity = 0
        totalStaffQuantity = 0
        totalProductionQuantity = 0
        totalSalesManager = 0
        totalSalesStaff = 0
        totalSalesProduction = 0

        Do While dr.Read = True

            dgvReportInvoice.Rows.Add(dr("TDate"), dr("InvoiceNo"), dr("ManagerQuantity"), dr("StaffQuantity"), dr("ProductionQuantity"))

            'Compute total manager, staff and production to Display
            totalManagerQuantity += dr("ManagerQuantity")
            totalStaffQuantity += dr("StaffQuantity")
            totalProductionQuantity += dr("ProductionQuantity")

            'Calculate the total amount per products
            totalSalesManager += (dr("ManagerPrice") * dr("ManagerQuantity"))
            totalSalesStaff += (dr("StaffPrice") * dr("StaffQuantity"))
            totalSalesProduction += (dr("ProductionPrice") * dr("ProductionQuantity"))

        Loop
```

But my code have an error when process calculation quantity (+=) as per below, will you help me how to solve my problem and what is the correct code, thanks.

P.S. The error come if there are no data on my table.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIboM.jpg

Regards,

Comment: Please do not put "Answered" or "SOLVED" in the title.  Here, the proper thing to do is to click the checkmark next to the answer which solved your problem.  Please take the [Tour] for more information and you might also want to read [Ask] - links to pictures of error messages are not well received.  You should also be using SQL parameters - these would simplify your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should null check your values before summing:

```
If not IsDBNull(dr("ManagerQuantity")) Then
  totalManagerQuantity += dr("ManagerQuantity")
End If
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew, Well with thank you for your help, it's work now, have a great day...